# Theme editing "post thumbnail" help

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

Is it possible to change the following code to display the "featured image" of a post/page using the style "background-image" instead of the image at the URL that is being pulled. I have messed around with the_post_thumbnail and get_the_post_thumbnail, etc.

Basically the theme is pulling a photo from somewhere else, but I want it to dynamically pull the featured image for whatever post/page that I am on.  Thanks to all that can help.

```
if ( $item['image'] ) {
   $style = ' style="background-image: url(\''.esc_url( $item['image'] ).'\');" ';
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'll need to post some more code. Right now, the code you've posted simply sets the variable $style to a string, but nothing is actually attempting to display it. Generally speaking, setting inline CSS via php is a bad idea. I would recommend you place the img element onto your page and style it separately as opposed to trying to set it as the background-image via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have set the featured image or any other from post with this code:

Get the image

```
$image_id=get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'full');
$image_url=$image_url[0];
```

Set the image as background

```
<div id="full" class="full float-left" style="background-image:url(<?php get_image_url(); ?>);">

Your content here.

</div>
```

Next, one example I made few years ago taking the image from random post, the image is set as background and cover class. [See sample](http://www.naturahouse.es/buscador/)

```
.full {
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```